# Disjunctive syllogism vs. modus ponens

Tags: logic

Let us assume the material conditional. Is disjunctive syllogism the same rule as modus ponens? If no, why?

Comment: It would be better to put your Question into a more precise form.  Presumably you have these terms ("material conditional", "disjunctive syllogism", "modus ponens") defined or illustrated in a text or other course materials.  Unfortunately Readers will have to guess at the meaning of 'the same rule" without more context.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on whether the deductive system you're working in (1) takes $\to$ as primitive and uses it to define $\lor$, or (2) takes $\lor$ as primitive and uses it to define $\to$, or (3) takes both $\to$ and $\lor$ as primitive, or (4) does something else.

For systems of sort (1), disjunctive syllogism is, in view of the definition of $\lor$, the rule "from $(\neg p)\to q$ and $\neg p$, infer $q$." This is a special case of modus ponens.

For systems of sort (2), modus ponens is, in view of the definition of $\to$, the rule "from $(\neg p)\lor q$ and $p$, infer $q$. This would be an instance of disjunctive syllogism if the second hypothesis were $\neg\neg p$ instead of $p$. So, if the system is set up (as some systems are) to make $\neg\neg p$ the same formula as $p$, then modus ponens is a special case of disjunctive syllogism. But in other systems, modus ponens would involve a combination of disjunctive syllogism and the rule "from $p$ infer $\neg\neg p$."

For systems of type (3), modus ponens and disjunctive syllogism would be different rules, simply because they involve different connectives.

Finally, for systems of type (4), I won't try to say anything because there are so many possibilities for doing "something else".